# Need help creating an RSS feed from Joomla 1.7 site

Tags: joomla, rss, feed

I'll try to make this clear. I need to make a few pages of my Joomla site into RSS feeds. I don't need the entire site.

I've run into several examples of how to do it, but none of them are really clear. Can anyone PLEASE tell me the easiest, most effective way to do it?
I've never worked with RSS feeds before, so please make it as simple and clear as possible.

I really appreciate it.
Thank you.

Comment: please oh please upgrade to Joomla 2.5!

Answer (score 0):

To make a feed in Joomla you just make a view.feed.php file that sits next to your view.html.php file. Basically you just follow the model from one of the category feeds. You are using the feed document.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand that. Is there any way you can kinda dumb it down I guess?

Comment: @SeanDavison - Have a look at [this](http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Component_Output_Types_and_Layout_Overrides)